# update MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Dear friends i am not an expert in php and need your help to solve an issue.

I am trying to create a page where i can call data from MySql and can edit/update it. The first part to display the data is done but i am unable to update it ... friends kindly help me solve this.

```
function Get_pages($mysql) {
$PageQuery = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE PageID = '$pageID'");

    while (($row = $PageQuery->fetch_assoc()) !== null) 
        {
            echo '<form action="page.php" method="post">';
            echo '<span class="lbl">Page Title</span>';
            echo '<input name="PageTitle" type="text" value="' . $row["PageTitle"] . '" />';
            echo '<span class="lbl">Page Content</span>';
            echo '<textarea class="txt-area" name="PageContent" cols="" rows="18">' . $row["PageContent"] . '</textarea>';
            echo '<input name="UpdateBtn" value="Update Page" type="submit" class="submit_btn"></form>';
        }

  // WHEN BUTTON CLICKED
if ($_REQUEST['UpdateBtn'])
    {

        $pageID = $_REQUEST["$pageID"];             
        $PageTitle = addslashes($_REQUEST['PageTitle']);
        $PageContent = addslashes($_REQUEST['PageContent']);


        $sql = mysql_query ("UPDATE pages SET PageTitle='$PageTitle', PageContent='$PageContent' WHERE pageID='$pageID'") or die ("Not Updating");  
    }
}
```

Comment: So, are you using `$mysql->query` or `mysql_query` to talk to the DB?  :P

Comment: I don't see an input type with `pageID`, first define a hidden type with $pageId in it and then capture ID using  
`$pageID = $_REQUEST["pageID"];`

Comment: this is my connection string: 

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "****";
$db_name = "cyberDB";
$mysql = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
 }

Comment: @AliKhan Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: I would recommend putting your `UPDATE` before your `SELECT`, so that you are getting the updated record in the select.

Comment: I added the hiddenfired with Page ID and changed 
$sql = mysql_query ("UPDATE
to
$sql = mysql->query ("UPDATE

But it still didnt work :(

Comment: @AliKhan it should be `$mysql->query`.

Comment: Thanks @Sean it works :)
Thanks alot my friends for guiding me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = mysql_query ("UPDATE
```

should be

```
$sql = $mysql->query("UPDATE
```

You are making connection with `mysqli_*` function and using `mysql_*` function for update , because of that your `UPDATE` is failing.